# AngularJS - Call function in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made a function `getAge()` in my `custom.js`. This function needs to be called in my HTML page.

So what i tried is like this :-

```
<td>{{getAge(user.basicinformation[0].dateofbirth)}}</td>
```

I can see no results.

How to call function in HTML?

Comment: so u need to create filter for this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Attach `getAge` and `user` to the `$scope` of the pages controller.

```
$scope.user = user;
$scope.getAge = getAge;
```

Make sure you're doing this in the controller and setting up the controller correctly. It won't work unless you've set up a controller with this DOM view and injected the `$scope` service into the controller.

Comment: It do works when i have this function with $scope in controller... As this function is used in many places, i have shifted this function in `custom.js` file. Doesn't work when function is in custom.js file

Comment: I would just create a reference to getAge and user within the scope, as in my answer. It can still be in the custom.js file. That's the only way you'll be able to access them in your {{ brackets }}

Comment: $scope.getAge = function(){   /**  function body */ } . And inside your html page call {{getAge()}}.

Answer (score 40):

So create a filter for `getAge`.

```
app.filter("getAge", function(){
   return function(input){
      // Your logic
      return output; 
   }
});
```

Then call it in HTML:

```
<td>{{ user.basicinformation[0].dateofbirth | getAge }}</td>
```

Comment: But @NitishKumar , `$scope.user = user` is _the_ way to do it in Angular. You would need to do it in your solution, anyway or else the filter couldn't access the `user` object.

Comment: I think 'filter' (for ng $filter) was a really poor choice of name for this, given that filter is also used in Angular (and in native JavaScript) when selecting a subset of items from an array. So, $filter and filter are two completely different things in Angular. The former should have been called formatter or transformer perhaps.